# Store original time zone with time stamp

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, postgresql-15

I have a table definition like the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE what_happened (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  action VARCHAR(128),
  created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

I want to be able to store the original time offset given for the value that was inserted in the `created` column. As I understand it, postgresql converts `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` to UTC internally, and then converts them again on fetch based on the value shown by `SHOW TIMEZONE`.

Let's say that we're adding a time stamp that has offset +0900, and that the offset is of interest. When we've added the value `2023-06-30T12:34:56+0900`, it is converted to UTC and stored in the database.

When the same record is fetched, the date is converted to the current time zone. If we're currently at CET +0100, it will display as `2023-06-30T04:34:56+0100`.

While this is correct, it's not very logical, and it assumes that the original time zone was not of interest.

So how could I store the original time offset, besides storing the value as text and casting it to date as required on read? Can I store the original time offset together with the time stamp, and use that? If so I don't see the right way, because changing the timestamp's offset with `AT TIME ZONE xyz` always returns a new value *without* time zone, which is not really helpful ([as described in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)).

So perhaps I need to:

1. Add a second column to save the time offset together with the timestamp
2. On display, convert the timestamp back to the original time offset, and build a valid ISO 8601 string append my original time offset information.

This seems a bit convoluted, and some of the steps aren't very straight forward. I'm hoping to avoid doing it manually with string operations.

Comment: You're slightly off in your understanding, in that the summer timestamp will still have the summer time zone offset - even if retrieved in the winter.  The offset used isn't the _current_ one, it's the one that was in effect at the given timestamp, in the active session time zone.

Comment: You are correct though that neither the time zone or offset are stored in a Postgres `timestamp with time zone` field.  Contrast that with `timestamp with time zone` in Oracle DB, `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server, and others - that _do_ retain such information.

Comment: I don't believe my understanding is off. How would you propose to fetch the original timestamp? With the table definition above, I set timezone to Europe/Berlin and inserted a row, then to Asia/Tokyo and inserted another, and then I changed timezone to US/Pacific, and all results have timezone -07. Postgres docs seem quite clear: `When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct.`

Comment: The current time zone is not the same as the current _offset_.  Yes, your results are influenced by the current time zone that you set, but the offset within that time zone is going to be the one that applies to the timestamp in question.  In other words, `Europe/Berlin` encapsulates both CET (UTC+1) and CEST (UTC+2), along with the rules that govern the transitions between those offsets.  If you use `Europe/Berlin` for both storage and retrieval, the offset won't be different.  (Unless the actual rules for `Europe/Berlin` are modified by the government.)

Comment: The [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that! So as long as we're operating within the same time zone, eg `Europe/Berlin`, postgres will take the actual date into account when setting the offset when I fetch the date from the DB. I tested by inserting dates in June and December, and regardless of whether I write +01 or +02 when I insert those dates, postgres returns +2 (CEST) for the June date and +1 (CET) for the december date! That's made it clearer, thanks!

Comment: Correct.  "Now" isn't part of the equation.  Only the active time zone, the data (offsets, rules, etc.) behind that time zone, and the UTC-based timestamp being converted.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to preserve the time zone that was entered is to save the time zone string in a separate column. Extracting the time zone is best done on the client side.

Comment: Extracting the time zone is one thing, but converting the internal UTC timestamp to the correct time zone, and then appending the correct timezone offset in the string, just seems like a whole lot of error-prone work for nothing. It occurred to me that the best way to handle this seems to be by keeping the `created` column as defined, but adding a second column `created_str VARCHAR DEFAULT now()`. This will cast the date to a string and seems to store the current timestamp as a time offset, just as I wanted. Uses a bit more space, but no more conversion or concatenation is necessary.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Matt Johnson-Pint, offsets and time zones are different things. A time zone like `Europe/Berlin` has a different time offset during summer time and winter time, and postgres keeps track of this. So my example using different offsets across daylight savings time boundaries requires no further attention, as it is already handled correctly by postgres when we're working in within the same time zone.

If there is a requirement that involved storing timestamps from completely different time offsets, and the original offset is of interest, the following might be useful.

It appears that storing both the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` *and* a string type storing the original value might be the way to go.

So the table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE what_happened (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  action VARCHAR(128),
  created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  created_str VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

and this provides the behaviour I was looking for. The main drawback is that the timestamp is stored twice.

```
postgres=# insert into what_happened (action, created, created_str) VALUES('test us pacific', '2023-09-27 11:26:35.844749-07', '2023-09-27 11:26:35.844749-07');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into what_happened (action, created, created_str) VALUES('test tokyo', '2023-09-28 02:26:35.844749+09', '2023-09-28 02:26:35.844749+09');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into what_happened (action, created, created_str) VALUES('test berlin', '2023-09-27 20:27:00.725301+02', '2023-09-27 20:27:00.725301+02');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from what_happened;
 id |    action       |            created            |          created_str
----+-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
  1 | test us pacific | 2023-09-27 20:26:35.844749+02 | 2023-09-27 11:26:35.844749-07
  2 | test tokyo      | 2023-09-27 20:26:51.236822+02 | 2023-09-28 02:26:35.844749+09
  3 | test berlin     | 2023-09-27 20:27:00.725301+02 | 2023-09-27 20:27:00.725301+02
(3 rows)
```

It would probably make sense to write a trigger that sets `created_str` from `created`, rather than supplying the same value twice all over the place. I can't store only `created_str`, because string sorting won't sort correctly across time offsets. If you don't require an index, then the following query orders the `created_str` correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM what_happened ORDER BY (created_str::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
```

Creating an index on `(created_str::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)` wasn't entirely straight forward either, but could probably be resolved with a wrapper function marked as IMMUTABLE.

Still, the safest bet might be to keep both `created` and `created_str`. Index and sort by `created`, and use `created_str` for display only, or for further processing when the original time zone is of consequence.

Comment: Not a bad approach, but personally I would store the just the offset independently, and probably as a number of minutes rather than as a string.